# How to use BootstrapVue's layout and grid system to arrange these checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a BootstrapVue table like this;

[image]

Here's the code for the table;

```
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    computed: {
      visibleFields() {
        return this.fields.filter(field => field.visible)
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        items: [
          { id: 1, first: 'Mike', last: 'Kristensen', age: 16 },
          { id: 2, first: 'Peter', last: 'Madsen', age: 52 },
          { id: 3, first: 'Mads', last: 'Mikkelsen', age: 76 },
          { id: 4, first: 'Mikkel', last: 'Hansen', age: 34 },
        ],
        fields: [
          { key: 'id', label: 'ID', visible: true },
          { key: 'first', label: 'First Name', visible: true },
          { key: 'last', label: 'Last Name', visible: true },
          { key: 'age', label: 'Age', visible: true },
        ]
      }
    }
  })
}

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
<b-checkbox
    :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && field.visible"
    v-for="field in fields" 
    :key="field.key" 
    v-model="field.visible" 
    inline
  >
    {{ field.label }}
  </b-checkbox>
  <br /><br />
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="visibleFields" bordered>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

I want to use BootstrapVue layout and grid system to arrange the checkboxes.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout

I want the checkboxes to be placed using BootstrapVue's layout and grid system as shown below;

```
<b-container class="bv-example-row">
  <b-row class="justify-content-md-center">
    <b-col col lg="12">1 of 3</b-col>
    <b-col cols="12" md="auto">Variable width content</b-col>
    <b-col col lg="2">3 of 3</b-col>
    <b-col col lg="14">3 of 3</b-col>
  </b-row>
</b-container>
```

What complicates matters is the html code for the checkbox which contains `v-for`. See below;

```
<b-checkbox
    :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && field.visible"
    v-for="field in fields" 
    :key="field.key" 
    v-model="field.visible" 
    inline
  >
    {{ field.label }}
  </b-checkbox>
```

I am using vue v2.6, BootstrapVue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks tricky, but doable.

1. Use v-for loop on `<b-col>` instead of `<b-checkbox>`
2. put `<b-col>` props like `col lg=12` as `fields` property as an object `{col:true,lg:12}`
3. use `v-bind` to user style props to `<b-col>`

Here is my attempt in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jhlee111/pen/xxYxONj) , I hope that I understood your intention correctly.

I assume that you are trying to render like below.

```
    <b-container class="bv-example-row">
      <b-row class="justify-content-md-center">
        <b-col col lg="12">
          <b-checkbox :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && fields[0].visible" v-model="fields[0].visible" inline>
            {{ fields[0].label }}
          </b-checkbox>
        </b-col>
        <b-col cols="12" md="auto">
          <b-checkbox :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && fields[1].visible" v-model="fields[1].visible" inline>
            {{ fields[1].label }}
          </b-checkbox>
        </b-col>
        <b-col col lg="2">
          <b-checkbox :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && fields[2].visible" v-model="fields[2].visible" inline>
            {{ fields[2].label }}
          </b-checkbox>
        </b-col>
        <b-col col lg="14">
          <b-checkbox :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && fields[3].visible" v-model="fields[3].visible" inline>
            {{ fields[3].label }}
          </b-checkbox>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
```

Adds new props property to your fields

```
fields:[ 
 { key: 'id', label: 'ID', visible: true, props:{ col:true, lg:12}},
 { key: 'first', label: 'First Name', visible: true, props:{cols:12, md:'auto' }},
 { key: 'last', label: 'Last Name', visible: true, props:{ col:true ,lg:2 }},
 { key: 'age', label: 'Age', visible: true, props:{col:true, lg:14} },
]
```

v-for loop  with v-bind props

```
  <div id='app'>
    <b-container class="bv-example-row">
      <b-row class="justify-content-md-center">
        <b-col v-for="(field,index) in fields" :key="index" v-bind="field.props">
          <b-checkbox :disabled="visibleFields.length == 1 && field.visible" v-model="field.visible" inline>
            {{ field.label }}
          </b-checkbox>
        </b-col>    
      </b-row>
    </b-container>

    <br /><br />
    <b-table :items="items" :fields="visibleFields" bordered>
    </b-table>
  </div>
```